Different results meta vs metafor for three-level meta-analysis of proportions
The R package “meta” has a function “metaprop” for meta-analysis of proportions and the argument “cluster” allows for three-level meta-analyses to be fitted. The R documentation (version 8.0-1) describes this as follows:

A three-level random effects meta-analysis model (Van den Noortgate et al., 2013) is utilised if argument cluster is used and at least one cluster provides more than one estimate. Internally, rma.mv is called to conduct the analysis and weights.rma.mv with argument type = "rowsum" is used to calculate random effects weights.

The function “rma.mv” is from the package “metafor” and has more options for comparing subgroups etc. so I attempted to replicate the result in “metafor” directly. While I can replicate the point estimate I get a small difference in the pooled standard error (and thus a different confidence interval). Does anyone know what is causing this difference?
I have included a reproducible example below.
# Load R packages
library(meta) #version 8.0-1
library(metafor) #version 4.6-0

# Sample dataset
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1:10),
  study = c("A et al", "A et al", "B et al", "B et al", "C et al", "C et al", 
            "D et al", "D et al", "E et al", "E et al"),
  n_positive = c(51, 103, 122, 201, 160, 112, 6211, 6187, 2339, 2470),
  n_total = c(124, 140, 306, 311, 229, 219, 13597, 12868, 5070, 5809) )
df <- escalc(xi = n_positive, ni = n_total, measure = "PLO", data = df)

# Analysis using metaprop
metaprop1 <- metaprop(event = n_positive, n = n_total, cluster = study, data = df)
# Analysis using rma.mv
rma.mv1 <- rma.mv(yi = yi, V = vi, random = ~ 1 | study/id, data = df)
# Analysis using rma.mv & the same study weightings as in metaprop
rma.mv2 <- rma.mv(yi = yi, V = vi, random = ~ 1 | study/id, data = df, W = metaprop1[["w.random"]])

# Comparison of pooled estimates (in logit form)
paste(metaprop1[["TE.random"]], metaprop1[["seTE.random"]])
# 0.0899361424942118 0.150816619366075
paste(rma.mv1[["beta"]], rma.mv1[["se"]])
# 0.0913959137416219 0.159661208321448
paste(rma.mv2[["beta"]], rma.mv2[["se"]])
# 0.0899361424942119 0.159663991953103

# Despite producing different pooled SEs 
# Both metaprop and rma.mv used the same study variances up to 16 decimal places 
summary( round(df$vi, 16) == round(metaprop1[["seTE"]]^2, 16) )
# TRUE for all 10 estimates

P.S. here is what the pooled results look like as proportions with 95% confidence intervals.
# Pooled results converted to proportions with 95% confidence intervals
paste0(
  round( logit2p( metaprop1[["TE.random"]]), 3)*100, "% (",
  round( logit2p( metaprop1[["TE.random"]] - 1.96*metaprop1[["seTE.random"]] ), 3)*100, "% to ",
  round( logit2p( metaprop1[["TE.random"]] + 1.96*metaprop1[["seTE.random"]] ), 3)*100, "%)" )
# "52.2% (44.9% to 59.5%)"
paste0(
  round( logit2p( rma.mv1[["beta"]]), 3)*100, "% (",
  round( logit2p( rma.mv1[["beta"]] - 1.96*rma.mv1[["se"]] ), 3)*100, "% to ",
  round( logit2p( rma.mv1[["beta"]] + 1.96*rma.mv1[["se"]] ), 3)*100, "%)" )
# "52.3% (44.5% to 60%)"
paste0(
  round( logit2p( rma.mv2[["beta"]]), 3)*100, "% (",
  round( logit2p( rma.mv2[["beta"]] - 1.96*rma.mv2[["se"]] ), 3)*100, "% to ",
  round( logit2p( rma.mv2[["beta"]] + 1.96*rma.mv2[["se"]] ), 3)*100, "%)" )
# "52.2% (44.4% to 59.9%)"


Is the difference due to the estimation method? {metafor::rma.mv} uses REML (restricted maximum likelihood) by default. According to the documentation, {meta::metaprop} calls {metafor::rma.glmm} which uses ML (maximum likelihood) by default. Try rma.mv(yi = yi, V = vi, random = ~ 1 | study / id, data = df, method = "ML").

In addition to the above codes it may be worth mentioning that the "metafor" documentation recommends including test="t" to generate confidence intervals using a t-distribution, similar to the Knapp-Hartung method (for "meta" this can be added using method.random.ci = "HK"). In addition, the "metafor" documentation also recommends using dfs = "contain" for an improved method of estimating the degrees of freedom of the t-distribution. Note these methods do not change the standard error, only the confidence interval. https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/misc-recs.html

Hello. Would you like to write this as an answer so that it's easier to find by others? (I got notified about the comment because of my own comment.)


dipetkov seems to be right that maximum likelihood estimator is used. But metaprop() calls rma.mv() to conduct a three-Level meta-analysis if the cluster argument is used, not rma.glmm().
If you manually set method.tau to "REML" results of metaprop() and rma.mv() are the same. When you set it to "ML" you will receive the results as reported above for metaprop1.
According to the general documentation the default for between study variance estimation should be the restricted maximum likelihood method. But when the logit transformation is used in metaprop() the function will set the method used for meta-analysis to "GLMM" (if the argument is missing) and based on this set the method for variance estimation (method.tau) to the maximum likelihood estimator "ML".
Because the cluster argument is specified the function changes the method argument to "Inverse" before meta-analysis is performed and uses "ML" as set before for variance estimation.
You could use the following to get the same estimates for metaprop() and rma.mv1:
    metaprop2 <- metaprop(event = n_positive, n = n_total,
    cluster = study, data = df, method = "Inverse")

    metaprop3 <- metaprop(event = n_positive, n = n_total,
    cluster = study, data = df, method.tau= "REML")

Or vice versa to get the same results with rma.mv() as with metaprop1:
    rma.mv2 <- rma.mv(yi = yi, V = vi, random = ~ 1 |
    study/id, data = df, method="ML")
    

